# Physicists Euler number conjecture

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, string-theory, singularity-theory

Physicist's Euler number conjecture says:

If $G \subset SL(n,\mathbb{C})$ is a finite group, $X=\mathbb{C}^n/G$ is the quotient space and $f:Y \rightarrow X$ a crepant resolution (always exists for $n\leq 3$). Then there exists a basis of $H^*(Y,\mathbb{Q})$ consisting  of algebraic cycles in one-to-one correspondence with conjugacy classes of $G$.

I have seen some works (by Reid,...) which date back to 2000. What are the recent results around this conjecture?

See : The McKay correspondence for finite sungroups of SL(3,C), by Miles Reid and Yukari Ito.

Comment: Do you know what this has to do with physics?

Comment: Physicists interested in String theory came up with this, while studying strings on the resolved Calabi-Yau,

See: L. Dixon, J. Harvey, C. Vafa and E. Witten, Strings on orbifolds

Comment: You might take a look at Miles Reid's Bourbaki seminar,
http://www.warwick.ac.uk/~masda/McKay/Bour/Bour.pdf
the book "Orbifolds in Mathematics and Physics" from 2001
and descriptions of results from the Newton Institute workshop
"Higher Dimensional Complex Geometry" in 2002 which are available on
their website. There must be more recent summaries of results than these, but I don't know where.


Comment: Yes, I have seen that, they are written around the same time.